# Creating Dynamic array in Jquery

Tags: arrays

I need to create a array which should have numbers starting from 8 and difference should be 8. The total number of elements has to be 4. How can I achieve this?

The Code I used is shown below and I used ICheck plugin.

```
$('#round-btn input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
    var arr = function(start=8, difference=8, total=4);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: _"Difference should be 8."_ What difference?

Comment: The Difference between the numbers should be 8.

Comment: I tried this var arr = $makeArray(start=8, difference=8, total=4);

Comment: This is not clear, and you didn't show anything. See [ask] to edit your question with the needed information and to show that you actually have done something. Thanks

Comment: Just curious. Why not simply declare it as `var arr = [8, 16, 24, 32]`? None of your requirements is dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery.makeArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) (if that's the one you meant in the comments), tries to create a native array from an 'array-like object', but you can use the vanilla [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method to dynamically create and initialize the array:

```js
 var arr = Array.from({length:4},  (v, i) => (i+1) * 8);
 
 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It gives me the result, Thanks.